# RedHat install mixing packages of different patch-level, dependency problem

Tags: rhel, yum

Problem: I need to install tomcat6-webapps. When I do that I afterwards get "dependency errors" when running "yum update".

I'm running RHEL 6.8 and when I try to install tomcat6 I will be offered tomcat6-6.0.24-95.el6 (note patch level (PL) "95") and there is no tomcat6-webapps package which matches that version.

If I try to install tomcat6-webapps, I will be offered tomcat6-6.0.24-83.el6_6 (note PL "83"). It could do fine with PL 83, but if complete the installation with all packages in PL 83 and then run "yum update" I get dependency errors. It is like there is a problem with repository as it does not have tomcat6-webapps-6.0.24-95.el6. Is there a way I can freeze at PL 83, which could be fine, or is there an another way to get webapps in PL 95?

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, search-disabled-
          : repos, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
repo id              repo name                                            status
rhel-x86_64-server-6 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (v. 6 for 64-bit x86 18,099
repolist: 18,099
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to fix similar problems:

```
yum install yum-versionlock
yum versionlock tomcat6-6.0.24-83.el6_6
```

then `update` will work again.

The only problem left is that the locked packages won't get updated.